# mbedTLS adding to the project

Tags: openssl, mbedtls

I`m a newbie and have some task to work with mbedTLS. Can I ask for an advice how to add it to my project in the makefile. I have not found a static library in the root repository after make or make install on mbedTLS.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output your compilation is located in the `library` folder, on your Mbed TLS root directory.
You can find additional information at the following articles:

- https://tls.mbed.org/kb/compiling-and-building/how-do-i-build-compile-mbedtls
- https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/compile-curl-with-mbedtls (steps 2,3 in the tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Use in juila kernal to add missing package as follows then run jupyter notebook

```
Pkg.add("MbedTLS")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have not found a static library in the root repository after make or make install on mbedTLS.

you should:

`make` **AND** `make install`

for:

- `make`

  - generated/output file to

    - `*.a` lib files inside `mbedtls/library`

      - eg: `libmbedcrypto.a`, `libmbedtls.a`, `libmbedx509.a`
    - executables(binary/script) files inside `mbedtls/programs`

      - eg: `ssl/ssl_server`, `pkey/rsa_sign`, etc.
- `make install`

  - Default install to: `/usr/local`

    - Copy header files inside `mbedtls/include` to `/usr/local/include/mbedtls`
    - Copy lib files (`libmbedcrypto.a`, `libmbedtls.a`, `libmbedx509.a`) into `/usr/local/lib/`
    - Copy (and rename, add prefix `mbedtls_`) to `/usr/local/bin/`

      - eg: `mbedtls_ssl_server`, `mbedtls_rsa_sign`, etc.

-> then you can use `mbedtls`'s **headers**/**libraries**/**programs**